# How the value get stored in registers in microprocessors

Tags: arm, qemu, microprocessors

I  am learning the assembly language of ARM. I think the register r3 should hold value 55 (10 + 20 + 25), but it does not. Could someone explain to me why?. I am emulating PXA255 connex board.

```
    .text
entry:  b start
arr:    .byte 10,20,25
eoa:

    .align
start:
    ldr r0, =eoa
    ldr r1, =arr
    mov r3, #0
loop:   ldrb r2, [r1], #1
    add r3, r2, r3
    cmp r1, r0
    bne loop
stop:   b stop
```

```
(qemu) info registers
R00=00000007 R01=00000007 R02=00000019 R03=00000037
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=00000000 R15=00000024
```

Comment: It's in hexadecimal.  R03 contains hex 037h which is 55 in decimal.

Comment: @NateEldredge. Oh ok, I get it. Thank you.